# Vertica Analytic function to count instances in a window

Tags: sql, vertica

Let's say I have a dataset with two columns: `ID` and `timestamp`. My goal is to count return IDs that have at least n timestamps in any 30 day window.

Here is an example:

```
ID Timestamp
1  '2019-01-01'
2  '2019-02-01'
3  '2019-03-01'
1  '2019-01-02'
1  '2019-01-04'
1  '2019-01-17'
```

So, let's say I want to return a list of IDs that have 3 timestamps in any 30 day window.

Given above, my resultset would just be ID = 1.  I'm thinking some kind of windowing function would accomplish this, but I'm not positive.

Any chance you could help me write a query that accomplishes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relatively simple way to do this involves `lag()`/`lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(timestamp, 2) over (partition by id order by timestamp) as timestamp_2
      from t
     ) t
where datediff(day, timestamp, timestamp_2) <= 30;
```

The `lag()` looks at the third timestamp in a series.  The `where` checks if this is within 30 days of the original one.  The result is rows where this occurs.

If you just want the `id`s, then:

```
select distinct id
from (select t.*,
             lead(timestamp, 2) over (partition by id order by timestamp) as timestamp_2
      from t
     ) t
where datediff(day, timestamp, timestamp_2) <= 30;
```

Comment: Ahh gotcha, so you're essentially using the lag(col, n) n part of the function to look back to find the 3rd record.  That makes sense.

Comment: This is perfect!

Comment: So generally if you're looking for n timestamps, it'd 
lag(col, n-1).

Comment: @ben890 . . . Either `lag()` or `lead()` will work.  And yes, the second argument would be `n - 1`.  Just be sure the arguments are in the right order for the `datediff()`.  Or use `abs(datediff())`.